# redux reducer does not update state after item removal

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am removing an item from the database via node which works fine. I then call the action:

```
.then(() => dispatch(removeBaseSuccess()))
```

From what I understand I do not need to pass an argument to the dispatched action, because we are not adding anything. Hence, the action function looks like this:

```
export const REMOVE_BASE_SUCCESS = "REMOVE_BASE_SUCCESS";
export const removeBaseSuccess = () => ({
  type: REMOVE_BASE_SUCCESS
});
```

A console log within this function does not trigger, but a console log before and after the dispatched action triggers, so I know `removeBaseSuccess` gets called. Moving on to the reducer:

```
else if (action.type === REMOVE_BASE_SUCCESS) {
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
        bases: [...state.bases]
    })      
}
```

I was under the impression that a returned state (with spread operator) would be enough to re-render the new state, since the item has already been removed. 
The page does not re-render, and the removed item still shows until i manually refresh the page

Comment: You should manually remove item from state. In your case you just assigning `state.bases` with same value as it was before. You can add base you want to remove from state into action creator:
`export const removeBaseSuccess = (base) => ({
  type: REMOVE_BASE_SUCCESS,
payload: base
});`
And then you can filter in reducer and  remove the `base` from state.

Comment: shouldn't there be a successful console log happening? I don't get an error message about them not working, as a matter of fact i get a blank console. The filter() function does not work, and i think it's because it never gets the data